# Search all in memory objects .NET

Tags: visual-studio-2010, memory-management

Is there a tool built into Visual Studio or a third-party add-on that would allow you to search all of the objects in memory for a certain string?

Here is a simple example to give an idea of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
Dim myClass as New Foo()
myClass.someVar = "Test"
```

I would like to be able to search all in-memory objects for the string 'Test' and see which objects have this value. I don't want to manually look through Quick Watch but have a tool that would do that kind of manual searching.

Comment: Usually for looking at the objects currently in memory, I would use the [SOS Debugging Extension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx) but I've no idea if it supports searching for a string in the way you need.  Might be worth a look?

Comment: Appreciate the link I'll check it out when I get some spare time.